# How to make crypto.randomBytes cause error

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

```
crypto.randomBytes(48, function (err, buffer) {
            if (err) {
              x = false;
              return;
            }
```

I need to create a test code where err is true. How to let crypto.randomByte cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

There will be an error if you provide an invalid value. e.g.

```
crypto.randomBytes(-1)
```

Comment: I am testing the code that is written, so crypto.randomBytes has the parameter 48 and it won't change during the running of code.

Comment: If it is always 48, i dont think there will be an error in any case